# I was making a program on BlueJ but i am unable to figure was is wrong in the code

Tags: bluej

I made a program in BlueJ to display the even numbers from 1 to 100.
But the Output is even numbers from 8 to 100.
So i request you to please help me to rectify my error. For this i would be thankful to you.

```
public class EvenNumbers1to100
 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a;
        for(a=2;a<=100;a+=2)
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
int a = 100;

System.out.println("Even numbers from 1 to " + a);

for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
   System.out.print(i + " ");
  }
}
```

You gotta go for a loop if you want to print all the numbers out

Comment: Yes thnxx for the answer but can u plzz tell why was my output wrong?